# Download Current WSJ.com Prime Rate

Tags: c#, quandl

I need to automatically download the current Wall Street Journal Prime Rate and load the data into my database.  What is the best method for downloading this data automatically?

I have come up with three possible solutions for doing this:

1. Scrape a HTML web page from WSJ.
2. Parse a RSS news feed from WSJ.
3. Use some API that I haven't found from WSJ.

Regarding solution 1, although I don't like solution 1 since it could easily break, it's the only one that I have worked out from end to end.  It appears I can scrape [this page](http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3020-moneyrate.html?mod=topnav_2_3000) with a WebRequest / WebResponse and read the text in this code:

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left" class="colhead">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="colhead">Latest</td>
<td class="colhead">Wk ago</td>
<td class="colhead">High</td>
<td class="colhead">Low</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text">U.S.</td>
<td style="font-weight:bold;" class="num">3.25</td>
<td class="num">3.25</td>
<td class="num">3.25</td>
<td class="num" style="border-right:0px">3.25</td>
</tr>
```

Regarding solution 2, although I can implement a RSS reader solution, I don't see a way to reliably anticipate verbiage for changes in the Prime Rate.  Therefore, I don't think this is as safe or reliable a way to get the data as solution 1.

Regarding solution 3, I haven't found any published API's for checking money rates like the Prime Rate.  If anyone knows of a web service or other API for checking money rates, then please let me know.

Comment: What are you using? Straight HTML plus some Ajax? ASP.NET? PHP?

Comment: I'm running a C# script task in a SSIS package to scrape the target HTML page once per day.  It works, but there has to be a better solution than this since I'm depending on the fact that the WSJ.com won't change their table or page layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented the following code to scrape the HTML and process the results:

**SSIS Package C# Script Task**

```
public void Main()
    {
        // Post the web page.
        try
        {
            // Set variables.
            bool fireAgain = true;
            Uri WebPageURI = new Uri("http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3020-moneyrate.html");

            // Post the web page.
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(WebPageURI);
            request.Timeout = (1000 * 60 * 60);
            request.Method = "POST";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string Output = reader.ReadToEnd();

            Dts.Variables["wall_street_journal_str"].Value = Output;
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "WebRequest:", WebPageURI.ToString(), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "WebResponse:", Output, "", 0, ref fireAgain);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Error:", ex.Message, "", 0);
        }


        // Return success.
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

**Stored Procedure Called by an Execute SQL Task**

```
SET @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML = SUBSTRING(@WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, CHARINDEX('Prime rates', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, 1), CHARINDEX('Canada', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, CHARINDEX('Prime rates', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, 1)) - CHARINDEX('Prime rates', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, 1))
    SELECT @RATE_CHANGE_DATE = CONVERT(DATE, RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, CHARINDEX('[', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, 1) + 23, CHARINDEX(']', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, 1) - CHARINDEX('[', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, 1) - 23))))
        , @RATE = CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), SUBSTRING(@WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, CHARINDEX('class="num">', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, CHARINDEX('U.S.</td>', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, 1)) + 12, CHARINDEX('<', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, CHARINDEX('class="num">', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, CHARINDEX('U.S.</td>', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, 1))) - CHARINDEX('class="num">', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, CHARINDEX('U.S.</td>', @WALL_STREET_JOURNAL_HTML, 1)) -12))
```

Ugly code, but it serves the purpose.  There are also several validation rules that run to verify the data is correct, but this is the core of what I used to scrape the value.

Answer (score 2):

There is a webservice for this, but it may not be worth the cost if all you want is the prime rate:

http://www.armindexes.com/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I checked the website and several of the links to more information on their web services don't appear to work right now.  I'll stick to the screen scraping solution since it has proven to be reliable (so far) and free. :P

Answer (score 2):

I'm about 5 years late, but thought I'd bring it up.
[Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/search) has a nice API for getting this information.

Comment: That is exactly the solution I would have used 6 years ago.  Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is looking for a solution to this, or similar problems today, +1 for Quandl, good API and you can usually find starter code in various github projects.